# SharePoint 2010 - Block library browse to anonymous access but allow URL references to content to display

Tags: library

We want to provide anonymous access to the contents of a library through URLs (like image references for the site), but we don't want a user to have library view/browse capability.  The site collection is a team site.

Answer (score 1):

With Publishing Sites in SharePoint 2010 there is a Feature called LockDown which disables automatically access to EditForm.aspx and AllItems.aspx for Anonymous.

This combined with the use of a Content Query Web part or a customized Data View (or a custom Web part - if you are in mood to go for the full-run) on a Page, should avoid anonymous to be able to get to views but still download Documents.

To transform the site into a Publishing site simply enable Publishing Infrastructure at the Site Collection level. You could have another Site be the actual Publishing Web to expose data in a Sub-Site - which still could remain a Team Site.

Comment: A bit hard to understand your suggestions for someone not an expert in SharePoint, but yes, I figured in out.  I guess I need to enable the site collections publishing infrastructure and then use the SiteCollectionImages library as it appears to have this feature set on it by default.

Comment: Is not about a single library, is about the whole site. Yes would need to enable at the site collection level, then whatever library where you store documents should behave the same. Have a look here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2007/05/12/anonymous-users-forms-pages-and-the-lockdown-feature.aspx